# Table coupling the product attributes and the orders in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Which table couples the orders and the product attributes of the related orders such as size, color and price?

For example, if my order contains a shirt, I need to get the color and size of the shirt through a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need get the product id from order and fetch super attribute for that product.

```
$order_id = 10002; // Your order ID;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($items as $item) {
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = ("SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        ce.sku,
        ea.attribute_id,
        ea.attribute_code,
        CASE ea.backend_type
           WHEN 'varchar' THEN ce_varchar.value
           WHEN 'int' THEN ce_int.value
           WHEN 'text' THEN ce_text.value
           WHEN 'decimal' THEN ce_decimal.value
           WHEN 'datetime' THEN ce_datetime.value
           ELSE ea.backend_type
        END AS value,
        ea.is_required AS required
    FROM catalog_product_entity AS ce
    LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea 
        ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ce_varchar 
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_varchar.entity_id 
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_varchar.attribute_id 
        AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS ce_int 
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_int.entity_id 
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_int.attribute_id 
        AND ea.backend_type = 'int'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text AS ce_text 
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_text.entity_id 
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_text.attribute_id 
        AND ea.backend_type = 'text'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ce_decimal 
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_decimal.entity_id 
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_decimal.attribute_id 
        AND ea.backend_type = 'decimal'
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime AS ce_datetime 
        ON ce.entity_id = ce_datetime.entity_id 
        AND ea.attribute_id = ce_datetime.attribute_id 
        AND ea.backend_type = 'datetime'
    WHERE ce.entity_id = ".$item->getProductId()."
  ) AS tab
  WHERE tab.value != ''")
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 
print_r($rows);
}
```

[Reference link](https://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/get-all-product-attributes-for-a-magento-object-using-sql.html)

Comment: Thanks, This SQL gives all attribute options of a given product. but I want to fetch order specific attribute options only. For example: if the order was placed for a t-shirt, I want to fetch the size and the color of the t-shirt ordered

Comment: ok for order specific you have get from this column SELECT product_options FROM sales_flat_order_item and in magento you will get like this from order item. $orderItem->getProductOptions(). in database saved this details in serialised format.